# Stunnel TLS authentication with multiple Authorities

Tags: ssl-certificate, tls, stunnel

I am trying to secure a rethinkdb cluster behind stunnel. The service needs to support multiple Certificate Authorities (CA). Currently I concat the accepted CAs into one file (/certs/ca.pem) but it seems stunnel will only accept connections that match the first certificate in the file.

My stunnel configuration:

```
foreground = yes
sslVersion = TLSv1.2
options = NO_SSLv2
options = NO_SSLv3

[driver]
client = no
accept = 28415
connect = 127.0.0.1:28015
cert = /certs/server.pem
key = /certs/server-key.pem
CAfile = /certs/ca.pem
verify = 2
```

Stunnel version 5.06

Stunnel's log:

```
2016.02.18 22:18:51 LOG5[18]: Service [driver] accepted connection from 209.136.228.130:58728
2016.02.18 22:18:51 LOG4[18]: CERT: Verification error: self signed certificate
2016.02.18 22:18:51 LOG4[18]: Rejected by CERT at depth=0: C=US, OU=Edit LLC, L=Fresno, O=Edit LLC, ST=CA, CN=jason-Lemur-Ultra
2016.02.18 22:18:51 LOG3[18]: SSL_accept: 140890B2: error:140890B2:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE:no certificate returned
2016.02.18 22:18:51 LOG5[18]: Connection reset: 0 byte(s) sent to SSL, 0 byte(s) sent to socket
```

And on the client side I get the following error:

```
SSL handshake failed: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_UNKNOWN_CA] tlsv1 alert unknown ca (_ssl.c:590)
```

I am not sure why stunnel says no certificate returned.

Edit: The error is coming from openssl. Here is how I can reproduce:

```
$ cat ca.cert.pem incomming-ca.pem > bigca.pem
$ openssl verify -CAfile bigca.pem incomming-ca.pem 
incomming-ca.pem: C = US, OU = Edit LLC, L = Fresno, O = Edit LLC, ST = CA, CN = jason-Lemur-Ultra
error 18 at 0 depth lookup:self signed certificate
OK
$ openssl verify -CAfile bigca.pem ca.cert.pem 
ca.cert.pem: OK
$ cat incomming-ca.pem ca.cert.pem > bigca.pem
$ openssl verify -CAfile bigca.pem incomming-ca.pem 
incomming-ca.pem: OK
```

Edit(2): Here I try to verify a signed certificate instead of sending a root CA

```
$ openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 1024
$ openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
$ openssl x509 -req -days 360 -in server.csr -CA ca.cert.pem -CAkey ca.key.pem -CAcreateserial -out server.crt
$ cat ca.cert.pem incomming-ca.pem > bigca.pem
$ openssl verify -CAfile bigca.pem server.crt 
server.crt: OK
```

Cool, but lets switch the order of `bigca.pem`

```
$ cat incomming-ca.pem ca.cert.pem > bigca.pem
$ openssl verify -CAfile bigca.pem server.crt 
server.crt: C = AU, ST = Some-State, O = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
error 7 at 0 depth lookup:certificate signature failure
140351186847392:error:0407006A:rsa  routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:block type is not 01:rsa_pk1.c:100:
140351186847392:error:04067072:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PUBLIC_DECRYPT:padding check failed:rsa_eay.c:721:
140351186847392:error:0D0C5006:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_verify:EVP lib:a_verify.c:233:
```

Comment: Server is using: `OpenSSL 1.0.1k` 
Client is using: `python 2.7.11` & `OpenSSL 1.0.1f`

Comment: Make sure the cat'ed file (bigca.pem) is **correctly formatted**: first cert `-----BEGIN` line, data, `-----END` line *with LF or CRLF*, and `-----BEGIN` line for second cert starts at the *beginning of* the next line or a subsequent line (after comments) but *nothing else*: no space, Unicode BOM or suchlike. Use `cat -A` or `sed -n l` or similar to be certain.

Comment: Verified bigca.pem was cat'ed properly. using `cat -A` to make the file actually causes openssl to have an error reading

Comment: No, I meant create 'bigca' then use `cat -A` or similar to *display* it and look to see if there any normally-invisible characters where they shouldn't be. But your edit worries me; it suggests the certs in `ca.cert.pem` and `incomming-ca.pem` have the **same (CA) name**. Try `openssl x509 -noout -subject -issuer` on each file separately. Every CA root cert should have the same value for subject and issuer and that value should be *different from any other CA cert*. If there are multiple CA certs *with the same name* then OpenSSL may be unable to use more than one of them.

Answer (score 2):

By configuring `stunnel` to **require** client certificates, using:

```
verify = 2
```

You are telling `stunnel` to drop/refuse any clients who do not provide a valid client certificate.  And this log message indicates that the client didn't provide a client certificate, and is thus rejected:

```
SSL3_GET_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE:no certificate returned
```

This we know.  Now, for **why** this happens.  That client-side message is our hint:

```
[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_UNKNOWN_CA] tlsv1 alert unknown ca
```

A TLS server *requests* that the client send its client certificate by sending a list of trusted CAs; these are the CA certificates that are in your `/certs/ca.pem` file.  The client, then, looks for a certificate that *comes from one of those CAs*; if the client does not have a certificate at all, *or* does not have a certificate which comes from one of those CAs, then the client will not provide a certificate at all.

The fact that your client is saying that it does not recognize any of the CAs sent by the server says that your client either *a)* doesn't have a client certificate, or *b)* its client certificate is from a CA that is not in the `/certs/ca.pem` file.

I am not sure which TLS client you are using, so I cannot help with that, but the above suggests that you check the configuration of the client certificate/key for that client, and check that the certificate configured for use by the client is from one of the CAs in your `/certs/ca.pem` file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am using python 2.7.11 on the client side. What is strange is I can get the client to connect without changing the CA certs param, rather I just use the first cert mentioned in `/certs/ca.pem` with the matching key. Why would stunnel say no certificate return when right above it says it rejected a self signed cert? I know those messages were caused by a single connection attempt.

Comment: Those log messages might from the OpenSSL error queue.  _I.e._ perhaps OpenSSL rejected the self-signed cert as part of the _verification_ process.  Then, later, `stunnel` asks for the _verified_ peer certificate, and gets none -- because it was rejected earlier.

Comment: That makes sense. I have been switching between two self signed certs, both of which are in `/certs/ca.pem`, if I switch the ordering in `ca.pem` I can get a previously rejected cert to be accepted but then it rejects the other.

Comment: I suspect that `stunnel`'s verification code is not really expecting to verify a self-signed cert provided by a client; such things are not very common (or recommended) in a production deployment.  If you use one of those CAs to issue a cert for your client, and then use that cert in your client, it _should_ work as you expect.

Comment: You are right. I can reproduce the failure locally :) Editing post to show.

Comment: Does this mean you will accept my answer for your question? :)

Comment: Client is definitely sending a cert because server is trying to validate it and failing. Server sends back an alert, and the client log message means it *received* the alert from the server saying 'unknown ca'.

Comment: Unfortunately sending a cert signed by one of the CAs produces the same results.